# Screen not showing properly

Tags: laptop, display, dell-inspiron

I am facing a problem with `DELL Inspiration N4110`.
[image]
[image]
One pic is the Screenshot of Desktop and another is Pic captured from mobile. It showing totally blurred screen. This blurred screen is from BIOS load time. Tried google but not found any solution.

Comment: If the screen shot of your desktop is normal and the monitor is showing that, there is either something wrong with the monitor (or its settings), your video card, or the connection between the two.

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the cable that is connecting your computer to the monitor?

Comment: Actually its a laptop

Comment: I tried re-installing Video driver.

Comment: There is still a connection between the motherboard and the screen. It's possible that connection has a problem, or the screen is faulty.

Comment: no screen was suddenly started working fine. but after two days it again in problematic condition.

Comment: It could be a heat related issue. Without any more information on the state of your computer when this occurs, there's not much we can do to answer. I have a very strong feeling that there is a problem with the connection with the screen to the motherboard or the screen itself. That would explain it being intermittent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It happened when I unscrewed my laptop for cleaning fan. It is because of a loose connection between display screen and motherboard.

I had to open again and tighten the loose connection and it worked well after that.